# Why are Images used as label not rendered correctly by GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld, image

When I try to render the label (png image) through GeoServer as an image, its quality is getting affected i.e. the image is not rendered sharply.

Are there any settings that need to done in GeoServer or the SLD file to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

In the image below we can see an original png (A) specified as a label graphic. Even if you specify in the layer SLD, that you want the graphic to be displayed at its native size and aspect ratio:

```
<VendorOption name="graphic-resize">none</VendorOption>
```

we see that GeoServer is rendering it using antialiasing (B).

There is an open ticket for this GeoServer issue ([GEOS-6196](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-6196)), so let's hope this will be solved soon, in the future.

[image]